# PHP Array - Remove Comma, If else statement

Tags: php, arrays, random, if-statement

I am relatively new to arrays, and struggling with the amount of information out there to solve my problem succinctly. This is as far as I have progressed.

My code:

```
<?php 

$imagearrdisplay = ",8,7,22,";

$displayitem = explode(",", $imagearrdisplay);

for($i = 0; $i < count($displayitem); $i++){

echo "
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/$displayitem[$i].jpg' /></div>
Count: $i = $displayitem[$i] ";

}

?>
```

It currently returns a result of:

```
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/.jpg' /></div>
Count: 0 =  
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/8.jpg' /></div>
Count: 1 = 8 
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/7.jpg' /></div>
Count: 2 = 7 
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/22.jpg' /></div>
Count: 3 = 22 
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/.jpg' /></div>
Count: 4 =
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. To remove the first and last comma within the imagearraydisplay when it explodes so that I do not end up with a blank image at the beginning and end.
2. Randomise the results of the array
3. Perform an if / else function to find the [0] and adjust the first result so that I can use css to style the image accordingly.

To be able to then produce an outcome that looks like:

```
<div class='firstbanner'><img src='/images/transitions/22.jpg' /></div>
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/7.jpg' /></div>
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/8.jpg' /></div
```

I know it's possible, though struggling through the maze of tutes out there. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$imagearrdisplay = trim(',8,7,22,', ',');
$displayitem = explode(',', $imagearrdisplay);
shuffle($displayitem);
```

To check if element is first just do:

```
if ( $i == 0 ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to remove `,` on the left and right. Use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) to randomize the array.

For the output initialize a `$class` variable to the first class, then iterate over all numbers, set the `$class` to the normal class after the first item:

```
$imagearrdisplay = ",8,7,22,";

$displayitem = explode(",", trim($imagearrdisplay, ','));

shuffle($displayitem);

$class = 'firstbanner';
foreach($displayitem as $item)
{
   $src = sprintf('/images/transitions/%d.jpg', $item);
   printf("<div class=\"%s\">\n  <img src=\"%s\">\n</div>\n", $class, $src);
   $class = 'banner';
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/upSnW9nx)

**Note:** If you use a [recent CSS version](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), you can identify the first banner as well with the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ltrim?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

```
$imagearrdisplay = ltrim(",8,7,22,", ",");
```

Also, you can use shuffle to randomize your array:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

To style the first image, you could use CSS instead.

```
.banner:first-child
{ 
background-color:yellow;
height:50px
width:50px
}

<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/22.jpg' /></div>
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/7.jpg' /></div>
<div class='banner'><img src='/images/transitions/8.jpg' /></div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sapphion/dBDqh/

Comment: I thought of using CSS though I do want to do a little more manipulation with the code to affect the end result, so in this instance it wasn't as suitable. Thank you for your input all the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split) can be used to split so that it drops empty pieces: `$chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`
2. PHP has [suffle](http://php.net/suffle) for array randomization.
3. For this, something like `$array[0] = str_replace(..)` (first element, I suppose), would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. An easy way to solve this would be to alter the string before you split it into an array, using e.g [`trim($imagearrdisplay, ',')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). But since you ask for a way to remove the first and last values have a look at [`array_pop()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`array_shift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).
2. To randomize the content in the array you can use [`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).
3. To get the first element you can use an if-statement on the `$i`. `if($i == 0) {`

Comment: Hi Marcus, Cheers for your response - The end result utilised all three of your responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim_comma($string) {
    $string = ($string[0] == ',') ? substr($string, 1, strlen($string)) : $string;
    $string = ($string[strlen($string) - 1] == ',') ? substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1) : $string;
    return $string;
}

echo trim_comma(",test,");
```

//test

this will remove your comma at the begining and at the end.